# Optional amount of declared variables in Bison Parser

Tags: c++, parsing, bison, rules

I'm new to bison (and flex, which I'm using as my companion to bison) and coding in general.  I'm trying to create a parser rule  that would allow input from a file that would allow for any number of variables that a file may have.

What I have currently is along the lines of:

```
body:
    BEGIN optional_statement optional_statement optional_statement END ';' ;

optional_statement:
    statement |
    ;
```

Obviously, this would be a finite solution, also obviously I have considered using a loop, but the bison manual that I have been using says "loops are beyond the scope of this manual".  I've tried searching around for other bison specific solutions to no avail.  If anyone is able to point me in the right direction toward formatting this loop or another solution, I would be very grateful.

Here is an idea of the kind of input I'm aiming for, could have one declaration or ten:

```
a: boolean is true
b: integer is 21
c: integer is 7
d: integer is 18
```

Comment: Are you talking about [this section of the FAQ](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Implementing-Gotos_002fLoops)? That's about how to implement a language with looping constructs (like a `for` loop), nit about how to write a grammar for lists of things. There are lists all over the manual. Lists of statements in an input. Lists of expressions, presumably for a function call (See [recursive rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Recursion).) And probably others.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write an unambiguous grammar with two consecutive optional components. Suppose only one component is provided:

```
    {   a statement;   }
```

Is this the first statement in `optional_statement optional_statement optional_statement`? Or is it the second one? Or is it the third one? If you actually succeeded in writing a grammar for a list of statements, how would you even know how many statements there are in the list, since there could be an unlimited number of invisible unrealised optional statements?

You might be thinking, "but I don't care". Fair enough, but the parser does care. It can only parse an input according to the syntax you provide, and its job is to report to you the way in which the input matched the grammar. So you need to help it by ensuring that every possible input matches at most a single parse.

Anyway, I don't think you meant that a block consists of an arbitrary number of optional unicorns. You meant that a block consists of zero or more statements, each of which exists. You can achieve that very simply:

```
block: '{' list '}'
list : %empty 
     | list statement
```

"`%empty`" is the preferred way of writing an empty right-hand side in modern (and even not-so-modern) Bison; in the dinosaurian epoch, it was common to mark empty right-hand sides with a comment `/* Empty */`, with the same semantics. As far as yacc/bison is concerned, you could just leave the right-hand side empty, but putting something visible is easier for human readers, who might not immediately see the nothingness.

That particular snippet was adapted pretty well directly from examples you will find in the [Bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Rules). Other common idioms you'll find:

```
/* A list of ONE or more statements */
list1: statement
     | list1 statement

/* A list of one or more expressions separated by commas */
listc: expr
     | listc ',' expr
/* A list of zero or more expressions separated by commas */
opt_listc: %empty | listc
```

The last one is what you would commonly use in constructing a grammar for function calls, for example.

If you've never before seen or written a context-free grammar, you probably should do a bit of reading. Wikipedia has some information (and semi-reliable links) in its entry about [Context-free grammars](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Rules), but if the subject actually interests you, you might want to seek out a book, such as John Levine's excellent little guide to *Flex and Bison*, published by O'Reilly's Safari Books.